# IIB 10.19 REST GET Operation Not getting invoked from postman

Tags: rest, postman, ibm-integration-bus

Trying to invoke a basic REST GET operation from browser and Postman.

From browser, the URL is `http://localhost:7800/restrequest_api/v1/4`

Where 4 is the UserNumber I'm passing.

It is getting invoked successfully.

But from PostMan I couldn't invoke it.

Tried `http://localhost:7800/restrequest_api/v1` with `Content-Type` header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and selected body as `x-www-form-urlencoded` with a Key UserNumber and Value 4

This is giving error as

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
    <p>
        BIP6311E: REST API '&apos;RESTRequest_API&apos;' does not support method '&apos;GET&apos;' for URL
        '&apos;http://localhost:7800/restrequest_api/v1&apos;'.
    </p>
    <hr>
</body>

</html>
```

Please Note: CORS are enabled:

```
mqsichangeproperties TESTNODE_hghatak -e default -o HTTPConnector -n corsEnabled -v true

mqsichangeproperties TESTNODE_hghatak -b httplistener -o HTTPConnector -n corsEnabled -v true

mqsistop TESTNODE_hghatak

mqsistart TESTNODE_hghatak
```

Below is the Swagger file which I used for development:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "title" : "RESTRequest_API",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "description" : "RESTRequest_API"
  },
  "paths" : {
    "/{UserNumber}" : {
      "get" : {
        "operationId" : "getUser",
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "The operation was successful.",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Output"
            }
          }
        },
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "description" : "Retrieve User",
        "parameters" : [ {
          "required" : true,
          "name" : "UserNumber",
          "in" : "path",
          "type" : "string"
        } ]
      }
    }
  },
  "basePath" : "/restrequest_api/v1",
  "definitions" : {
    "Output" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "firstName" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "lastName" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "userDetails" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "userNumber" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "host" : "localhost:7800"
}
```

what is the issue?

Comment: Is there are a reason why you are specifying the content-type header as 'x-www-form-urlencoded'? I don't see anything in your Swagger that requires it.

Comment: @Himadri - could you tell if my below answer helped ?

Comment: yes rohan, it's not url encoded. Did your trick successfully. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select GET as your operation in POSTMAN and in BODY tab in postman select "none" option. Ensure you are using the same URL in postman as you are using in browser i.e. **http://localhost:7800/restrequest_api/v1/4**

### Explanation:

Your swagger file indicates that its a **GET** operation being performed hence there is no requirement of payload being sent. So choosing the content-type is not applicable. In the parameters section of the swagger file, the following is mentioned **"in" : "path"**, which means that you have to pass a path parameter in your url i.e. **http://localhost:7800/restrequest_api/v1/4 where 4 is your path parameter** in your example. You can go through the following postman link that provides further details on sending parameters => https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#sending-parameters